# Why would the condensing unit fan shut off but not the compressor?

Tags: hvac

We have an allegiance 12 unit circa 2001, model 7a2024a100a3, the fan starts up and runs for about 5 minutes then shuts off, the compressor is still on and seems to build up a bit the "flush" or so it sounds, then build up again. I can turn the fan blades manually. When the fan stops we get warm air in house, when it runs it is cold.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I have not, it fires up fine and then cycles through the fan workingh En not working...

Answer (score 1):

> It fires up fine and then cycles through the fan working and not working [while the compressor is still on].

If it's NOT the capacitor, then the fan motor is **kicking out on over heat** via its integral thermal overload. You need a new fan motor (save the blades from the old one).

---

I don't bother with testing capacitors. Both fan and cap get swapped out on a 14yo unit. If it can start and run for a while, I highly doubt it's the cap, but you should replace that $5 item regardless. The bearings on the motor may be fine but that doesn't mean the windings are ok (failed windings will lead to thermal overload even though it 'works').

Most integral overload sensors reset themselves. That's why it comes and goes every five minutes.

Comment: I can feel the heat rising from the condenser when the fan is not turning.

Comment: @Jrod0264 But the compressor's still running, right?

Comment: yes still running and Dan blades are not "locked" up

Comment: @Jrod0264 - Free spinning blades don't mean it's all good. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

This could be normal operation. Now and then the unit will reverse cycle to defrost; manufacturers use different means to achieve this. Quirky or unusual setups should be mentioned in paperwork. Look up troubleshooting.

Comment: Steve! Your answers have valuable info, but are hard to read, so most visitors won't get much from them. A little work on punctuation (spaces after commas and periods) and spelling will really broaden your value in the community. (Thanks.)

Comment: As an example, I've edited your answer, fixing the punctuation and removing the signature (which should be in your profile, if anywhere). If you do this, then visitors will benefit, and will upvote your answers, in turn giving you more privileges. You clearly have a lot you could contribute to the site; I'd love to see you be more effective.

Comment: Consentration is requried on difficult questions,my  English suffers as a result, I am trying.Most important I feel is to be right.Thanks for comment Steve uk engineer.

Comment: Understood. You do what you can, you don't what you can't. I'll get off your case now (for at least a little while...). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 1993 York 3 ton unit, I replaced a fan motor in outside unit this spring. But last night I noticed it stopped blowing and compressor was still running. Then it kicked back on in a minute or so. After reasearching documents, it appears that original was a 2 speed 850rpm and 525rpm which switches at 70deg. Outside temperature had dropped with a cool front. So when it switched there was nothing connected to the low speed side. One problem with "replacement parts ".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, fan ran for either 15 seconds, 2 hrs or a day or so but each time it would seem to die but yet the fan looked like it was very controlled, not binding, no bad noises,really confusing.  Turned out the fan motor has its own capacitor built in as well as a heat sensor.  Either can shut down the fan motor.  Unless you can find those parts and are very handy,just change the motor and get back to getting cooled off.